# Byte stored in integer format to Hexadecimal Conversion

Tags: c, hex, byte

I have integer variable which has bytes. eg. int var = 128. so, 128 is 128bytes. How can I convert this into hexadecimal format in C language.

Answer (score 2):

A given integer on a given hardware architecture is always represented the same way.

If you are trying to print it out, you can use `printf`.

```
 printf("%x\n", var);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these:

```
%x    Unsigned hexadecimal integer                | 7fa
%X    Unsigned hexadecimal integer (uppercase)    | 7FA
```

so you need this:

```
printf("%x", var); // you can replace %x to %X if you want to be uppercase
```

Answer (score 0):

Number at memory location is in binary form. You can convert it into any base (or format) you want.

So, `int var = 128` is stored in a memory location. You can print it in any format. To print it in hexadecimal, use

```
 printf("%x", var);
```

It will print var in hexdecimal.